# Passing files as an argument in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running a `docker` container with below command

```
    docker run -d -v /root/myapp/solution/dataFile:/myapp/data -p 1080:1081 8cb989ef80b5
```

The dataFile contains some data which is needed for the successful run of container. Next I am trying to put use docker-compose to lauch the container with below docker-compose.yaml file

```
   version: "3.7"
   services:
   myapp:
       image: myserver/myapp:latest
   ports:
     - "1080:1081"
  volumes:
     - /root/myapp/solution/dataFile:/myapp/data
```

But when I ran the `docker-compose` command it is failing with below error

```
 myapp_1  | 2021/12/07 11:58:37 error while reading the file "/myapp/data": read /myapp/data: is a directory
 $ ls -l
 total 0
 drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            15 Dec  7 11:49 dataFile
 [node1] (local) root@192.168.0.18 ~/myapp/solution
 $ pwd
 /root/myapp/solution
```

On inspecting the contents, I can see `dataFile` is created at a directory because of which the script is failing . How to pass the arguments as a file so that the `docker-compose` succeeds.

Comment: Are you sure the `dataFile` exists on your host system as a plain file before you start?  If it doesn't, Docker will automatically create it as a directory, which matches what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are lacking information about the container, you run and what it actually tries to do, we must make some assumptions. One of those assumptions would be, that "/myapp/data" is supposed to be a file, but you specify as the volume a directory.
So `/root/myapp/solution/dataFile` is a directory in the time, the container is being run. If `dataFile` is not existent beforehand, it is being created as a directory by default, therefore you should create is as a file first, before adding it as a volume to your container.

Usually it does not make a lot of sense, to link a volume to a file, if it does not exist before running the container. It should either be present inside the container, or on your file system. In this case, it probably is neither.

It might help for a more precise answer, if you added some more information about the details of your container. I would edit my answer correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs . The file is created when we run the container and is mapped with a file on the host .. Any way to specify a file in docker-compose ?

Comment: Is the file /myapp/data »created by the container« or just being read? If it is not existing »before« the container starts, you must mount the whole directory in order to see the created file after start of the container. If the container »requires« a file at /myapp/data at »start time«, you must create that file, for example with "touch /root/myapp/solution/dataFile" »before« starting the container, in order to mount it.